# OCCI - SQL performs >= instead of >

Tags: database, oracle, numbers, occi

EDIT:
Looks the problem is in occi::Number:
My bind variable is big number so I am using the biggest occi::Number can get - long double.
I made a test and got this problem:

I put 1260365696006 in occi::Number and printed it as (unsigned long) and got 1260365696005 ==> **different** number!!

Any idea?

```
 long double ld1 = (long double)1260365696006;
 oracle::occi::Number num2(ld1);
 LOG("num2=%.9Lf num2(unsigned long)=%ld", (long double)num2,   (unsigned long)num2);
                                    
    results are:
    num2=1260365696006.000000000 num2(unsigned long)=1260365696005
```

### Original problem:

I am using occi 21 version on linux.
I am running the next query with the max value from the table, so I expect to get no results. But I am getting the row with that value.

```
select * from CacheMessages where message_id > $message_id_p order by message_id, message_number"
```

When I run on another table, I get correct results (no results):

```
select * from Bank where bank_obj_num > $bank_obj_num
```

What can be the reason/s for '>' to return '>='?

1. There is no rounding issues (all are integer values).
2. Not much records (3500).
3. The parameters for both queries, are type int64 (~ 1,260,364,000,000).
4. This table has a field that is populated by a trigger. (not the 'where' field).
   The ***CacheMessages*** table structure is:

```
 CREATE TABLE "CACHE_MESSAGES" 
   (    "MESSAGE_OBJ_NUM" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MESSAGE_TIME" DATE, 
    "MESSAGE_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
    "MESSAGE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "SERIAL_ID" NUMBER, 
    "MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR), 
     CONSTRAINT "CACHE_MESSAGES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MESSAGE_OBJ_NUM", "MESSAGE_TIME")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) LOCAL
 (PARTITION "CACHE_MESSAGES_MAXV" 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TBS_RNDSAN65" )  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TBS_RNDSAN65" 
  PARTITION BY RANGE ("MESSAGE_TIME") 
 (PARTITION "CACHE_MESSAGES_MAXV"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TBS_RNDSAN65" ) ;
  CREATE INDEX "CACHE_MESSAGES_IND_01" ON "CACHE_MESSAGES" ("SERIAL_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) LOCAL
 (PARTITION "CACHE_MESSAGES_MAXV" 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TBS_RNDSAN65" ) ;
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "CACHE_MESSAGES_SERIAL_TRG" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON CACHE_MESSAGES
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
iCounter cache_messages.serial_id%TYPE;
cannot_change_counter EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
Select cache_messages_serial_seq.NEXTVAL INTO iCounter FROM Dual;
:new.serial_id := iCounter;
END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN
IF NOT (:new.serial_id = :old.serial_id) THEN
RAISE cannot_change_counter;
END IF;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN cannot_change_counter THEN
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cannot Change Counter Value');
END;
```

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem.?  Eg What is the max value, and what was your parameter value?

Comment: Try wrapping the $ with TO_NUMBER: `where message_id > TO_NUMBER($message_id_p)` just be sure the bind isn't coming in as a string and Oracle is converting the column to a string to compare alphabetically. Also try numbers below and above the 2,147,483,648 limit for a signed 32bit, just to be sure you really are 64 bit the whole way and it isn't being read as a negative number. Also, ensure that the value in the database is an integer.. if it has any decimal precision that could be a source of confusion too. Lastly, you should test using a string bind: `message_id > TO_NUMBER('$message_id_p')`

Comment: Do you have bind variables?  Please update the question with some exact OCCI code snippets you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all.
Nothing was relevant :-(
I solved my problem by using different type of variable.
It was defined as long long (which is not supported by the OCCI), so lucky me, I found that I can use 'long'. It is enough for me (The system was initially was built for 32-but systems).
So, now there were no problems to move the right value to the OCCI.
BTW, when trying to print the value I sent to OCCI, it returned me 5.999999999 instead of 6 (Which I sent him as long double (OCCI::Number)).
Thanks.

Comment: Don't just talk about the code, include it in the answer. Use a code fence for formatting it.